# Grabing the username in a php login session

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, security

I been doing alot of research with php logins and how they work for a while. I came across this site a couple of days ago. http://www.intechgrity.com/create-login-admin-logout-page-in-php-w/#comment-25300. Looking at it I notice that it was using `session_register` which is a huge problem in PHP 5.3.  I begin playing around with it and I got the login part to work with no problem, but for some reason I can't get the username to show in the header of the admin page.  What I want is: `<h1>Welcome To Admin Page Username</h1>` and it gives me `<h1>Welcome To Admin Page</h1>`.  I was wondering if it's because I have 2 sessions using the same var?

My changes from the tutorial:

check_login.php -

```
    <?php
define(DOC_ROOT,dirname(__FILE__)); // To properly get the config.php file
$username = $_POST['username']; //Set UserName
$password = $_POST['password']; //Set Password
$msg ='';
if(isset($username, $password)) {
    ob_start();
    include(DOC_ROOT.'/config.php'); //Initiate the MySQL connection
    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($username);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $myusername);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM login_admin WHERE user_name='$myusername' and user_pass=SHA('$mypassword')";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbC, $sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php" 
        $_SESSION["admin"]= $myusername;
        $_SESSION["password"]= $mypassword;
        $_SESSION["name"]= $myusername;
        header("location:admin.php");
    }
    else {
        $msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
        header("location:login.php?msg=$msg");
    }
    ob_end_flush();
}
else {
    header("location:login.php?msg=Please enter some username and password");
}
?>
```

admin.php -

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
define(ADMIN,isset($_SESSION["name"])); //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
if(isset($_SESSION["admin"])){ //If session not registered
header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
else //Continue to current page
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Welcome To Admin Page Demonstration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome To Admin Page <?php echo ADMIN /*Echo the username */ ?></h1>
    <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p> <!-- A link for the logout page -->
    <p>Put Admin Contents</p>
</body>
</html>
```

These are the only 2 pages I did changes.  Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:**  I tired the changes from everyone who answer and still got a blank.  I just going to give up on it.  It puzzles me how it work with the old code but not with the new code.  Thanks for all the help.

**UPDATE 2:**  Got it to work thanks to Gumbo suggestion about using `var_dump();`.  What I did is I took everything from *check_login.php* and placed it into the *admin.php* and went from `array(0){}` to `array(3) { ["username"]=> string(6) "admin" ["admin"]=> string(6) "admin" ["password"]=> string(5) "************" }`.

Thanks everyone for all of your help.

Comment: You should remove the calls to stripslashes. `mysqli_real_escape_string` is enough to guard against injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`isset`](http://php.net/isset) does only return a boolean value depending on whether the given variable exists or not; but it does not return the variable value if it exists.

Do this instead:

```
session_start();                  // Start the session
if (!isset($_SESSION["admin"])) { // If session not registered
    header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
    exit;                         // Stop execution of current script
} else {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    define('ADMIN', $_SESSION["name"]); //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
}
```

And note that you’ve used `$_SESSION["name2"]` and not `$_SESSION["name"]` in your *check_login.php*.

Comment: Setting it to '!isset' keeps redirecting me back to the login page, but if I set it to 'isset' I can login in but no name appears.

Comment: @blackbull77: What does `var_dump($_SESSION)` print?

Comment: I'm not sure if I put it in the right place, but it comes out at `array(0) {
}`.

Comment: @blackbull77: You need to put it somewhere after `session_start`. And if that output is in that case the one you’ve mentioned, then your session management does not work properly. It’s probably the session ID that is not properly transmitted. Check the session ID on both pages calling `session_id` after `session_start`.

Answer (score 6):

There are two things wrong.  Change all of the **old** to **new**.  (Did this way for nicer formatting.)

```
define(ADMIN,isset($_SESSION["name"])); //old
define(ADMIN,$_SESSION["name"]); //new
```

---

```
$_SESSION["name2"]= $myusername; //old
$_SESSION["name"]= $myusername; //new
```

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns a boolean, not the value.

Edit: As stated by Gumbo, a semi-colon is not needed after the constant ADMIN.  Therefore, there are only two errors.

Comment: [The ending semicolon is not necessary.](http://php.net/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation)

Comment: @Gumbo how come it is not executing right on Codepad then?  http://codepad.org/UvXFwKGy

Comment: Please follow the [provided link](http://php.net/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation) and read: “The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block.”

Comment: @Gumbo Silly me did not realize it was a link.  I knew about the closing PHP tag, but did not know that it applied to everything else too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    <h1>Welcome To Admin Page <?php echo $_SESSION['admin'] ?></h1>
```

Comment: The question was edited significantly after I answered the question. Please attempt constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

In check_login.php you are assigning $_SESSION["name2"] but in admin.php you are using $_SESSION["name"]. Besides, as others have already pointed out, you define ADMIN as a bool value rather than the username...